# How do i create a collision detection x value (simple ping-pong game) ActionScript3

Tags: actionscript-3

So, i have created a simple ping pong game that is working

when the ball hit the (top/bottom) of the player it bounces back vertically. the problem is when the ball hits the (left/right) of the player side it does not bounce horizontally.

so far this is the relevant code that should be revised or add something to:

```
var ballrec:Rectangle = new Rectangle(sball.x-(sball.width*0.50), 
            sball.y-(sball.height*0.50), 
            sball.width, sball.height);

var playerrec:Rectangle = new Rectangle(splayer.x-(splayer.width*0.50), 
            splayer.y-(splayer.height*0.50), 
            splayer.width, 
            splayer.height);

if(ballrec.intersects(playerrec)){

            var intersection:Rectangle = ballrec.intersection(playerrec);

            accelerationy *= -1;
            yspeed *= -1;
}
```

advance thanks! sorry for the trouble

Comment: You have to also invert the x-axis values on hit.

Comment: i know that, but how do you check if it hits the side(and not the top/bottom)?

Comment: You do it allready.. `rectangle.intersects()` you may also want to watch this about collision detection: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4iWqRyuo65M i recommend to use that starling framework in your game.

Comment: Use hitTest in a while loop, inside you can identify your borders

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but i dont understand which object is the moving ball and i cant comment because my reputation doesnt let me but to check if the ball hits the top/bottom sides of your stage just try:

```
if (ball.y <= 0 || ball.y >= stage.stageHeight){

    //do whatever when the ball collisions with the top or bottom
}
```